# HD network media player with 100% open source buildable firmware

Tags: media-player, embedded-linux

I am looking to develop an application for HD media player, and looking to purchase one which has 100% open source buildable firmware I can modify. I looked around and all of media players I could find, that advertise they are open source, only have kernel open. Main application usually is proprietary, so they only supply sources of linux kernel and GPL utilities.

What I am looking is the player for which I can actually build complete firmware myself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [DreamBox](https://www.dream-multimedia-tv.de/en), it is Linux based, have network, etc.

Comment: At the bottom of the information page for a device, I found this link
http://developer.elitedvb.net/listprojects.php?curr_dir=64. Then, there is the independent projects, e.g. Enigma.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try EHP-608. It's based on sigma design 8635c. It's a network media player.